# How can I get the DOM element of a ngFor array?

Tags: angular, ngfor

How can I get the actual element of a ngFor, so that I can work with it in the Component.ts

Example:

```
//.html
<div *ngFor="let element of elements">
      <md-card>{{element}}
           <button (click)="delete()">Delete</button>
     </md-card>
</div>

//.ts
   public delete() {
        mydata.delete(this.element)    //how to delete the actual element?
    }
```

Comment: `<button (click)="delete(element)"`

Comment: I encourage you to give a try at @GünterZöchbauer advice using `public delete(YourElementClass: element) {}`

Comment: yes, that answered my question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Maintaining Index of Element**

You can maintain the index in loop and pass to the method.

```
//.html
<div *ngFor="let element of elements; let i = index;">
      <md-card>{{element}}
           <button (click)="delete(i)">Delete</button>
     </md-card>
</div>

//.ts
   public delete(index:number) {
      // if your elements is an array, you can use splice.
     elements.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

**Passing The Full Element**

If your data structure has a way to delete based on an element being passed to it. Arrays don't have a delete method that takes an object, you have to splice. You can just pass the object like this

```
//.html
<div *ngFor="let element of elements">
      <md-card>{{element}}
           <button (click)="delete(element)">Delete</button>
     </md-card>
</div>

//.ts
   public delete(element:ElementType) {
        mydata.delete(element)    //how to delete the actual element?
    }
```

Comment: or you can pass the element to the method :)

Comment: @ALSTRA I edited my answer to reflect that scenario, but I wasnt sure if you had the method delete from your data since if elements was an array you wouldnt have that method available to you.